# How could I ignore a field in json response?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
@JSonIgnore
private String password;
```

I have given the above field in my model class, but It did not work for the POST method.

Error:null value in column "password" violates not-null constraint

Comment: How are you returning the response as JSONString or string

Comment: you remove nullable = false

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal - Is there any other way? I know that if I remove nullable = false, I will get the answer, but the field must not be null.

Comment: @Sreemat Response is returning as JSONString

Comment: you mean that you do not want to send the password. "you want to hide the password field in response right?

Comment: Yes, in response I dont want to get password field

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal I want to send the password in request, but hide in the json response. Could you please help me?

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("key", "value");
String str = (String)json.remove("key");

Comment: i came up with new idea. you just remove the field in the response then send it.

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal I dont understood completely. I am new to java and json. could you please explain with example?

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal The json request is `{ "mail" : "abcd@gmail.com","password" : "efgh"}'`and my response must be `{"userId":12235, "mail":"abcd@gmail.com"}`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm you read this tut.

Comment: @Kumaresan Perumal Okk

Comment: Can you add the method code here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add @JsonIgnore only **on getter method**.

```
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@JsonIgnore
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

or

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had solved the problem.
This was my old code:
    `@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)`

```
`@JSonIgnore`

`private String password;`
```

Instead of JSonIgnore, we can use JSonProperty. Below is the code:

This is the new code:
    `@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)`

`@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)`

`private String password;`

Thanks to everyone for helping...

Answer (score 1):

You have set the field to `nullable = false` - which means the password must not be null, hence some code verification does not allow you to pass a null value into `password`.

Comment: What should I do to ignore password in json response.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to archive. I suppose you want to store (`POST`) a new user(?) and don't want to send the password in the `json` response. But you need a password which is NOT null in the first place or you are not allowed to create the object

Comment: I need a password that is NOT NULL and this(password) should not be there in json response.  This is what I want? Could you help me?

Comment: When should the user choose his password? Is it already contained in the post request - Then there should be no problem. Is it set in a later step - remove the `nullable = false` or set a default password. Or verify if the user can be created before trying to persist the user - depending on your use case.

Comment: I need to examine once more because nullable = false cannot be removed according to my requirement and the password is set in later step

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up the request and the response:

- @JsonIgnore will ignore the field when it gets parsed to JSON as a response object. (E.g. for some API call)
- If you POST data which should be creating an object with a nonnull password, the request must have this parameter. @JsonIgnore does not change anything to that.

If you want to have the POST data being valid while not sending the password, you will need to create an object which you can save apart from the password. This could be a saveable superclass, where the subclass has only the password, or just another class which has a relation to another class which holds the password field.

If you don't want the separate class, you'll either have to add the password to your request or change nullable attribute in the @Column annotation to true.